# Proof on inequality $|x-1|$

Tags: solution-verification

I had an inequality problem when dealing with proof

$0\lt|x-1|\lt a$, then $|x-1||x-1|\lt a^{2}$ ?

does this sound right?

Comment: That looks right, though it would look better with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $0\le x<y$, then we have $$x^2<y^2$$

The function $f(x):\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}, f(x)=x^2$ is an increasing function on the nonnegative domain.